# How to get nosetests to run tests in sequence?

Tags: python, nose

No matter what I try, I can't seem to get `nosetests` to run my unittests in sequence instead of concurrently. I want it to first run one test, and then when that test is done, to run another test, etc. However it keeps on interweaving them, which because of the tests I'm running is very troublesome. What can I do to turn this off? I've been looking around and the closest thing I've seen is running it with `--processes=0`, which didn't work.

Comment: Do you have env `NOSE_PROCESSES` set?

Comment: Can't reproduce your error, `--processes=0` works for me. What python/nose versions you use?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have the NOSE_PROCESSES environment variable set in your terminal:

on linux/OS X:

```
echo $NOSE_PROCESSES
```

on windows:

```
echo %NOSE_PROCESSES%
```

Additionally check if you have a setup.cfg file in your project directory. If you do and you have a line like the following it may be overriding your command line switch:

```
processes=4
```

Comment: I have a similar guess (in comments), but the way args are passed to multiprocess plugin this seems to be unlikely

Comment: Yes it seems like the command line switch should take precedence regardless. But since the default should be 0 anyway he might have it set to non-zero in the environment or configuration and then maybe his command line switch is not taking for some other reason.